# Problem with my method in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class like so:

```
class Qtree
{
public:
    Qtree();
    Qtree(BMP img, int d);
private:
   class QtreeNode
   {
   public:
      QtreeNode* nwChild;  // pointer to northwest child
      QtreeNode* neChild;  // pointer to northeast child
      QtreeNode* swChild;  // pointer to southwest child
      QtreeNode* seChild;  // pointer to southeast child
      RGBApixel element;  // the pixel stored as this node's "data"

      QtreeNode();
      QuadtreeNode copy(QuadtreeNode & n);

   };
```

And so the question is on the copy method. It makes a copy of a given node and returns it.

```
QtreeNode Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(QtreeNode & n) {
   QtreeNode *newNode;
   //....
   return newNode;
}
```

And then I call copy from my Qtree copy constructor:

```
root=QtreeNode::copy(*tree.root); //each tree has a root pointer
//have also tried many different things here, but dont really know what to put
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot call member function ‘Qtree::QtreeNode* Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(Qtree::QtreeNode&)’ without object

and

error: no matching function for call to ‘copy(Qtree::QtreeNode&)’
```

Comment: Also, I do realize that my copy method returns a pointer, even though it shouldnt. This just goes along with my overall confusion. I just dont know how to work this..

Comment: `copy()` is not declared static.

Comment: Why not just make a proper copy constructor instead of this non-canonical nonsense?

Comment: What would be the benefit of creating a copy constructor as opposed to what I'm doing?

Comment: @bitmoe: It means you don't have any confusion regarding the lifetime of the copy you create, it means your object is copy-safe (which at the moment it is not), it means this problem goes away, etc etc...

Comment: But my copy method uses recursion to make a copy of all child nodes, and their child nodes, etc. Would I still be able to do this with a cc?

Comment: @bitmoe: Yes. That's what they're designed for. In fact you *must* have one, because at the moment if your object is copied then the ownership of the pointers becomes shared, and the destructor that you should have breaks.

Comment: But how would recursion work in a cc? Wouldnt I need a helper method?

Comment: @bitmoe: No. You copy the members, each of which should have its own proper copy constructor defined. The C++ language solved all this several decades ago.

Comment: I do not really understand the situation. How relate `Qtree::QtreeNode` with `QuadtreeNode`? Where is declaration of `QtreeNode Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(QtreeNode & n)`? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
static QuadtreeNode copy(QuadtreeNode & n);
```

or better create copy constructor.

`copy` is instance method, it means that it can be run only with object provided. It's internal signature as a function is:

```
QuadtreeNode copy(QtreeNode* this, QuadtreeNode & n);
```

So you have to pass to parameters. Notation `obj->copy(..)` is used, but it is actually passing `obj` as first parameter.

Comment: So wait after I have made it static, is there anything else I need to do? Do I need to follow your second step too? I'm still getting errors when calling my method. If I have a method: `Qtree::Qtree(Qtree const & tree) { root=QtreeNode::copy(tree.root); }`Why do I get an error with this?

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(Qtree::QtreeNode* const&)’
quadtree.h:71: note: candidates are: static Qtree::QtreeNode Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(Qtree::QtreeNode)`

Comment: @bitmoe change either signature or arguments.

Comment: @bitmoe now you have another problem. Your argument doesn't match with signature. Try: `*(*tree.root)`

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of your class Qtree::QtreeNode to be able to call the copy() method on it.

You cannot do :

```
root = Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(*tree.root);
```

But you can do :

```
Qtree::QtreeNode myQtree;
root = myQtree.copy(*tree.root);
```

Comment: @gablin it would, but it is bad idea.

Comment: It should not. The object created like that will be immediatly destroyed. I guess. If not... As Andrey says... You should not do that.

Comment: Yeah, I would never _actually_ do that, but I got curious to whether it would work or not. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
QtreeNode Qtree::QtreeNode::copy(QtreeNode & n) {
   QtreeNode *newNode;
   //....
   return newNode;
}
```

I could be wrong, but you define the function as returning a (QtreeNode), then don't you return a (QtreeNode *) ?

Comment: This should have been a comment. But yes, you are correct (and the question author also notes about this in the question). The first line should probably read `QtreeNode newNode;`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was looking for the comment button: Apparently I can't comment with a low reputation. At the time of posting I don't think that comment was there either.